# How do you test for unmatched tables when using outer join (Many to Many)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, how to you test for unmatched tables when using an outerjoin on a many-to-many relationship.

I'm working with 5 tables/objects.

- **Program:** Art class, spanish class, etc
- **Session:** Child of Program, each program has several sessions, session stores date/time for each class
- **Student:** Students can enroll in Programs
- **Enrollment:** Associates students with Programs
- **Attendance:** Associates students with Sessions. Created lazily (not until needed)

In the below example I'm trying to find student absences. I perform an outerjoin on the Attendance table because the Attendance object doesn't always exist. I want to return rows where `Attendance.absent == True` or rows where `Attendance` is not matched (ie not yet created).

```
class Session(BaseModel):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # list of Attendance objects for students that attended this session
    attendance = db.relationship(Attendance, backref="session") 

    @classmethod
    def get_absences(cls, student):
        # I'm trying to return a list of sessions where this student was absent
        # The query joins the Program table so it can join
        # the enrollment table, so it can filter for enrollments
        # for this student and then return sessions where 
        # the Attendance object has not been created or Attendance.absent == True
        return (
            cls.query
                .join(Program)
                .join(Enrollment)
                .filter(Enrollment.student_id == student.id)
                .outerjoin(Attendance)
                 # Attendance == None is not correct
                .filter(or_(Attendance == None, Attendance.absent == True))
        )


class Attendance(BaseModel):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    session_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('session.id') )
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.id'))
```

So `Session.get_absences()` obviously doesn't work because `Attendance == None` isn't overloaded and doesn't generate sql. How do I return sessions where the `Attendance` object hasn't been created for a given `Student` / `Session` pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a standard relational model with referential integrity enforced by FK constraints.

Basically, you need a query like this:

```sql
SELECT st.id, se.id, a.absent
FROM   student         st
JOIN   enrollmant      e  ON e.student_id = st.id
-- JOIN program        p  ON p.id = e.program_id  -- omit middleman
JOIN   session         se ON se.program_id = e.program_id -- p.id -- omit middleman
LEFT   JOIN attendance a  ON a.student_id = st.id
                         AND a.session_id = se.id
WHERE  st.id = 123                                -- given student ID
AND   (a.student_id IS NULL OR a.absent);         -- missing or "absent"
```

Returns a list of student ID and session ID where the student was either `absent` or no entry was found.

The full list of candidates is generated from joining to `enrollment`, (`program`), and `session`. The final `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to `attendance` determines the missing ones.

I commented out the join to `program`, as this is just a middleman we don't need for the query. (Unless you need to assert a matching row in that table.)

I added `absent` to the result to tell the difference between missing and "absent" entries.

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your query to allow a full outer with `Attendance` -- also, `Attendance.absent` with no matches will return `null` so match your query for those results :

```py
cls.query\
    .join(Program)\
    .join(Enrollment)\
    .filter(Enrollment.student_id == student.id)\
    .join(Attendance, isouter =True, full=True)\ 
    .filter(or_(Attendance.absent == None, Attendance.absent == True))\
    .all()
```